# What is the probability that you catch a fish over 60 inches an less than 50 inches?

Tags: statistics, probability, mean, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

You’re going to catch a fish in the river. You know that its size is normally distributed with mean 56 inches and standard deviation 7 inches. What is the probability that you catch a fish over 60 inches? What is the probability that you catch a fish less than 50 inches?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about many fish, not just one fish having a mean of 56 inches and sd of 7.

If the size is normally distributed with the mean and sd given above, then the probability of X, the size, being > 60 inches is 1 - the probability that it is less than 60 inches.

Standardizing so we can use tables, we want the probability that Z < (60-56)/7 = 0.5714. Which is, according to standard normal tables, 0.7157. So 1 - 0.7157 = 0.2843.

In R:

```
1 - pnorm(60, 56, 7)
# [1] 0.2838546
```

Less than 50 inches?

(50 - 56) / 7 = -0.8571. So probability that Z < -0.8571 = 0.1957

In R:

```
pnorm(50, 56, 7)
#[1] 0.195683
```